# Outbound Call dtmfAnswer Plays on top of NCCO from answer_url

Tags: vonage

Hi I'm having trouble trying to control an outgoing call that dials an extension before executing a few NCCO objects.  Basically the use case is the following...

1. Initiate an outbound call with a supplied dtmfAnswer.
2. User answers the phone and the dtmf tones are played.
3. Then we execute a couple NCCO objects to say some text.
4. Call ends.

The issue that I am seeing is that I can successfully hear the dtmf tones playing, but it appears to be occurring at the same time as my NCCO objects returned from the answer_url. Basically step2 and step3 are occurring at the the same time.  Is there anyway I can force the dtmfAnswer to play followed by the content from my configured answer_url?

Thank you!

**Creating Outbound call**

```
body = {
    "to": [{"type":"phone", "number": "xxx", "dtmfAnswer": "ppp123ppp"}],
    "from": {"type":"phone", "number": "xxx"},
    "answer_url": ["testing-123-ngrok.io/answer"],
    "answer_method": "POST",
    "event_url": ["testing-123-ngrok.io/event"],
    "event_method": "POST"
}
```

**Sample NCCO returned from answer_url**

```
NCCO = [{
    "action": "talk",
    "text": "Welcome to a Voice API I V R.",
    "voiceName": "Amy",
    "bargeIn": False,
},
{
    "action": "talk",
    "text": "Press 1, for maybe, and 2, for not sure, followed by the hash key.",
    "voiceName": "Amy",
    "bargeIn": True,
},
{
    "action": "input",
    "submitOnHash": True,
    "eventUrl": [const.PUBLIC_HOST + "/answerbla"]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to update this comment as I got a workaround from talking with some implementation folks.  It looks like there isn't a direct NCCO that you can create to delay the beginning of the answer_url content. However, there is an SSML element you can add to your leading talk NCCO since Nexmo supports SSML.

```
NCCOS = [
    {
        "action": "talk",
        "text": "<speak><lang xml:lang='es-ES'><break time='10s'/>Hola</lang></speak>"
    },
]
```

This will wait for 10 seconds before the Nexmo TTS starts saying "Hola". The duration you put in the time attribute can be pretty accurately be calculated via the length of the DTMF tones.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this question. The answer *should* be that the `dtmfAnswer` will be played and then the NCCO from your `answer_url` will follow ... however I've tested it and I also experience the tones but no NCCO. I'm really sorry that you've run into this - we're looking at it on our side and I'll keep you posted.

If you still need to be able to play DTMF tones into a call, there isn't an NCCO action for this but you can do it programmatically by calling the API and supplying the Conversation ID. There are some examples available in various languages here https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/building-blocks/play-dtmf-into-a-call and the API docs are here: https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice#startDTMF

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @lorna-mitchell, thanks for getting back!  I'm seeing the same thing here, so I must have tweaked something in my sample code so I'll have to look into that.  I want to stay away from needing to make a separate HTTP call to play DTMF digits because that relies too heavily on timing requests just right which seems a little unreliable.  Because we would need to make an HTTP call to initiate the call (provide a dtmfAnswer), PUT to play DTMF, and another PUT to update the conversation with out NCCO steps.